# Cannot understand and resolve the errors of method overriding of this program

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
public class test extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
JFrame f;
JPanel p;
JButton b;
test()
{
    f=new JFrame("My Frame");
    p=new JPanel();
    f.add(p);
    b=new JButton("Button");
    p.add(b);
    f.setSize(100,100);
    f.setVisible(true);
    b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ae)
        {
            System.out.print("mouse clicked");
        }
    });
    b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent ae)
        {
            System.out.print("mouse Entered");
        }
    });
    b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent ae)
        {
            System.out.print("mouse Exited");
        }
    });
    b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent ae)
        {
            System.out.print("mouse Pressed");
        }
    });
    b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent ae)
        {
            System.out.print("mouse Released");
        }
    });
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new test();
}
}
```

Errors are as follows:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
C:\Users\SHUBHENDU\Documents\test.java:19: <anonymous test$1> is not abstract and      does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in        java.awt.event.MouseListener
        {
        ^
C:\Users\SHUBHENDU\Documents\test.java:26: <anonymous test$2> is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener
        {
        ^
C:\Users\SHUBHENDU\Documents\test.java:33: <anonymous test$3> is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener
        {
        ^
C:\Users\SHUBHENDU\Documents\test.java:40: <anonymous test$4> is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener
        {
        ^
C:\Users\SHUBHENDU\Documents\test.java:47: <anonymous test$5> is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent) in java.awt.event.MouseListener
        {
        ^
5 errors
```

Comment: Not related, but your class name should be capitalized so it's not confused with methods. `public class Test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a concrete Java class (non-abstract class) you have to implement all the methods that an interface has, of course if your class implements that interface.
So **add unimplemented methods** of `MouseListener` interface to your code. But you are adding a new `MouseListener` to the same button every time. That's not the way it is used. You can/should implement all `MouseListener` methods in the same code body. **Remove** redundant `MouseListener` additions to your `JButton b`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that familiar with AWT but it appears that you have a non-abstract class (`test`) which does not implement the abstract methods of an interface (`MouseListener`).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

You need to implement:

```
mouseClicked(MouseEvent)    
mouseEntered(MouseEvent)
mouseExited(MouseEvent) 
mousePressed(MouseEvent)    
mouseReleased(MouseEvent)
```

If your class **was** abstract, you would not be required to implement these methods (the onus would be on the next non-abstract subclass to do so).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to override one method of the `MouseListener` interface, you could use `MouseAdapter` as follow:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click");
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse was clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanx buddy it was also helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

To fix those errors...

```
1) Remove "implements MouseListener"

2) Change MouseListener to MouseAdapter
```